# Multiple GeoCoordinateWatchers in WP7 Cause Bad Data

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

If I have multiple GeoCoordinateWatchers in a WP7 application, they seem to cause conflict with one another. I would assume that if I have a watcher setup like:

```
new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High) { MovementThreshold = 0 }
```

and another setup like:

That the value from the first should be extremely accurate whereas the second one should be used as a point of reference.

```
new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default) { MovementThreshold = 1000 };
```

However, the second one causes the first coordinates to jump all over the place. If I comment out the second, the first works as expected. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the same accuracy and see if you get the same values.